# Stack - Push implementation

Tags: file, pointers, stack, structure

Can anyone please explain here what is the issue in the below code because of that it is not producing any errors as well as any output?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Stack{
        int size;
        int top;
        int data;
        int *arr;
    } Stack;

void push( Stack*s ,  int data)
    {
            s->top++;
            s->arr[s->top] = data;
    }
int main()
    {
     struct Stack *s;
     s->size = 100;
     s->top = -1;
     s->arr = (int* ) malloc (s->size* sizeof(int));
     push( s, 180);
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect? Nothing in that code produces output.

Comment: ...Ah, but you never allocate space for the `Stack`. You are causing Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you write `struct Stack *s;` which is just a wild pointer pointing to some space in memory with no reserved space, so you should do instead :

```
struct Stack *s = (struct Stack* ) malloc (sizeof(struct Stack));
```

to reserve space for your wild pointer.

even my compiler gave me this warning, so make sure to turn on all compiler warnings on yours.

> Variable 's' is uninitialized when used here

this is the full code with only this small modification:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Stack{
    int size;
    int top;
    int data;
    int *arr;
} Stack;

void push( Stack*s ,  int data)
{
    s->top++;
    s->arr[s->top] = data;
}

int main()
{
    //struct Stack *s = (struct Stack* ) malloc (sizeof(struct Stack));
    struct Stack *s;
    s->size = 100;
    s->top = -1;
    s->arr = (int* ) malloc (s->size* sizeof(int));
    push( s, 180);
    printf("stack top data = %d\n", s->arr[s->top]);
}
```

and this is the output:

```
stack top data = 180
```